how to make cells in <td> tag
I have a table like this :




No
Name Product
Type
Num of Units




1
ADA
B112
3 Pcs


2
ADA
B253
1 Pcs


3
ADA
K23
6 Pcs


4
DUZK
l1
10 Pcs


5
DUZK
l5
10 Pcs


6
Naro
NX
1 Pcs



I have this SQL :
$query = "SELECT *, GROUP_CONCAT(`Code Unit`) AS Codeunit, COUNT(`Code Unit`) AS NoU FROM `stock goods` GROUP BY `Name Product`, `Type` ORDER BY `Name Product`, `Type`";

NoU : Num of Units
Actually I have Code Units in my table
Here is my code:
echo "<table id='customers'>";
echo "<tr>

<th id='No'>Nomor</th>
<th id='nameproduct'>Name Product</th>
<th id='type'>Type</th>
<th id='NoU'>Num of Units</th>
<th id='Click'>Botton Click</th>
</tr>";

$nomor_urut = 1;
  
$nomy = 1;
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $nomy = 1; // Initialize $nomy here
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>" . $nomor_urut."</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row["Name Product"] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row["Type"] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row["NoU"] . "</td>";
    $Type2 =  explode(',', $row["Type"]);
    $Kodeunits = explode(',', $row["Kodeunit"]);
    $dara = $row["Type"] . " - " . $row["Jumlah"] . "<br>";

    echo "<td><button onclick='myFunction(" . json_encode($row["Nama Produk"]) . "," . json_encode($row["Type"]) . ",". json_encode($Kodeunits) . ")'>List Stock</button></td>";
    echo "</tr>";
    $nomor_urut++;
}

echo "</table>";

I hope to convert to the table like this:



No
Name Product
Type
Num of Units




1

B112
3 Pcs


2
ADA
B253
1 Pcs


3

K23
6 Pcs








4

l1
10 Pcs


5
DUZK
l5
10 Pcs








6
Naro
NX
1 Pcs



I hope every same name of Name Product would be pressed into 1 row so it looks neat

What is your question? do you want to know how to add rowspan and colspan? It is not clear

An easier thing to do, is to output the product name only the first time it occurs, and leave the cells in the next rows empty. For that, you simply need to compare the product name of the current row, to that of the previous - and depending on whether they are the same or differ, you react accordingly. [...]

[...] What you want, additionally requires that you count the number the products occur beforehand. Then each time you encounter a new product, you output it into a table cell with the rowspan set accordingly - and for the following records for that same product, you output no table cell for the product name then.

Which dbms are your using? (Your SQL query is product specific.)

The main problem with your code is that you are very quick to echo the results as fast as you get them, so by the time you get the second record having the same product name as the previous one, you've already written the first one. Instead, you need to grasp the concept of separation of concerns, a principle, which, in your case was violated by assuming that you want/need to echo out all the results as soon as you get them. But it's actually not the case, because you will need to first parse the records in order to know what the rowspan will end up to be.
Instead of echoing everything, separate the echoing into a function, which I will call echoTemplate here and do something like this:
    $prefix = "<div id='test'>Stock Barang</div>";

    // output data of each row
    $prefix .= "<div>";
    $prefix .= "<table id='customers'>";
    $prefix .= "<tr>";
    
    $prefix .= "<th id='KodeUnit' rowspan='2'>Nomor</th>";
    $prefix .= "<th id='namaproduct' colspan='2'>Nama Product</th>";
    $prefix .= "<th id='type' rowspan='2'>Type</th>";
    $prefix .= "<th id='Jumlah' rowspan='2'>Jumlah Stock</th>";
    $prefix .= "<th id='Button' rowspan='2'>Botton Click</th>";

        $nomor_urut = 1;
      
            $nomy = 1;
    $records = [];
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $nomy = 1; // Initialize $nomy here
        $Type2 =  explode(',', $row["Type"]);
        $Kodeunits = explode(',', $row["Kodeunit"]);
        for ($index = 0; $index < count($Type2]; $index++) {
            $record = [
                [
                    'value' => $nomor_urut
                ],
                [
                    'colspan' => 2,
                    'value' => $row["Nama Produk"]
                ],
                [
                    'value' => $Type2[$index]
                ],
                [
                    'value' => $Kodeunits[$index]
                ]
            ];
            if ($index === 0) {
                $records []= [];
            }
            $records[count($records) - 1][]=$record;
        }
    
        //echo "<td><button onclick='myFunction(" . json_encode($row["Nama Produk"]) . "," . json_encode($row["Type"]) . ",". json_encode($Kodeunits) . ")'>List Stock</button></td>";
        $nomor_urut++;
    }

    $suffix = "</table>";
    $suffix .= "</div>";
    echoTemplate($prefix, $records, $suffix);

And then implement echoTemplate so that it actually echoes out the stuff you generated.

First in your php code, determine consecutive identical Name Product by adding other identifiers, followed by the rowspan tag to assemble your table_td.

You have to count the number of product with same name. As your Database query has a group by and order by clause so the products with same name will be grouped together. Then you have to add rowspan in the product name <td>
<?php
// MYSQL Query. Please change the column names as per your table name
$query = "SELECT `name_product`, `type`, `num_of_units` AS NoU FROM `Products` GROUP BY `name_product`, `type` ORDER BY `name_product`, `type`";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);

if ($result) {
    $result = mysqli_fetch_all($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC); // Make an associative array from the result
    $currentProduct = "";
    $rowCount = 0;
    echo "<table border='1'>"; //I have added border, if you have css class, you can remove border
    echo "<tr>
     <th>No</th>
        <th>Name Product</th>
        <th>Type</th>
        <th>Num of Units</th>
      </tr>";
    $serialNumber = 0;
    foreach ($result as $index => $row) {
        //in the loop check if the product has changed
        if ($row['name_product'] != $currentProduct) {
            if ($index > 0) {
                echo "</tr>"; // Close the previous rowspan row
            }

            $currentProduct = $row['name_product']; //new current product
            //total count of a particular product. 
            //Reference : https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-count-values.php 
            $rowCount = array_count_values(array_column($result, 'name_product'))[$currentProduct]; 
            
            echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td>" . ++$serialNumber . "</td>"; 
            echo "<td rowspan='{$rowCount}'>" . $row['name_product'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row['type'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row['NoU'] . "</td>";
        } else {
            echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td>" . ++$serialNumber . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row['type'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row['NoU'] . "</td>";
        }

        echo "</tr>";
    }
    echo "</table>";
} else {
    echo "Error executing query: " . mysqli_error($conn);
}
?>

Result:

